# Is there a R function to remove rows that do NOT start with a time stamp?

Tags: r, text, data-cleaning

I am trying to familiarize myself with R by cleaning some data from a Whatsapp chat between myself and a friend. So far, I have converted the .txt to a .csv 
but i have an issue.

I would like my row to be formatted like this:

,,

When a chat is too long, it starts on a new line (row). So then i end up with a row like:

How can I clean the file so that all my rows start with a timestamp?

I have been trying to work with regular expressions. I have been following a tutorial https://journocode.com/2016/01/31/project-visualizing-whatsapp-chat-logs-part-1-cleaning-data/ but the results are not what I expected

```
# Add 5 empty rows to end to make space for shift
chat <- cbind(chat, matrix(nrow = nrow(chat), ncol = 5))

cat("Rows without time stamp:", length(grep("^\\D", chat[,1])),
    "(", grep("^\\D", chat[,1]), ")", "\n")
for(row in grep("^\\D", chat[,1])){
  end <- which(is.na(chat[row,]))[1] #first column without text in it
  chat[row, 6:(5+end)] <- chat[row, 1:(end-1)]
  chat[row, 1:(end-1)] <- NA
}
chat <- chat[-which(apply(chat, 1, function(x) all(is.na(x))) == TRUE),]
```

I end up with a very messy csv file. time stamps all over, chat all over. Def not the outcome I had in mind

Comment: Can you share a reproducible example or `dput(head(chat))` for your data frame (assuming it is named chat)?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote [a package a little while ago to take care of WhatsApp data](https://github.com/JBGruber/rwhatsapp). I will use the important parts of the [source code](https://github.com/JBGruber/rwhatsapp/blob/master/R/rwhatsapp.R) and the example data to show you how you can do that on your own. First, let's grab some example data:

```
chat_raw <- scan(text = "
12/07/2017, 22:35 - Messages to this group are now secured with end-to-end encryption. Tap for more info.
12/07/2017, 22:35 - You created group 'Tes'
12/07/2017, 22:35 - Johannes Gruber: <Media omitted>
12/07/2017, 22:35 - Johannes Gruber: Fruit bread with cheddar <U+263A><U+0001F44C><U+0001F3FB>
13/07/2017, 09:12 - Test: It's fun doing text analysis with R
isn't it?
13/07/2017, 09:16 - Johannes Gruber: Haha it sure is <U+0001F605>
28/09/2018, 13:27 - Johannes Gruber: Did you know there is an incredible number of emojis in WhatsApp? Check it out:
", what = character(), sep = "\n")
```

This leaves us with an object that is just like what we would get by using `readLines()`: every line of text is one element of the character vector. Now we can extract the timestamps using regular expressions:

```
time <- stringi::stri_extract_first_regex(
  str = chat_raw,
  pattern = "^\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4}, \\d{2}:\\d{2}"
)
```

`\\d{2}` is a number of with two characters, \d{4} a number with four characters. You will have to alter the characters in between the numbers to get your correct date format. I use `stringi` here for speed but many people find `stringr` more convenient and the functions work pretty much in the same way. Now the `time` vector looks like this:

```
time
#> [1] "12/07/2017, 22:35" "12/07/2017, 22:35" "12/07/2017, 22:35"
#> [4] "12/07/2017, 22:35" "13/07/2017, 09:12" NA                 
#> [7] "13/07/2017, 09:16" "28/09/2018, 13:27"
```

We grabbed a time from every line but the one without a timestamp. We can loop through all the lines without a timestamp and add the characters in there to the line before:

```
for (l in which(is.na(time))) {
  chat_raw[l - 1] <- stringi::stri_paste(chat_raw[l - 1], chat_raw[l],
                                         sep = " ")
}
```

`which(is.na(time))` in this case will return only 6 as this is the only line where time is `NA`. So you can read `chat_raw[l - 1]` as `chat_raw[5]`, i.e. the fifth line of `chat_raw`. `stringi::stri_paste` is the same as `paste()`, hence line 6 is added to line 5. You can choose a differnt seperator if you want. I choose `"\n"` to mark a newline in my package. Now the `chat_raw` and `time` vector still have this additional element that is useless to us now. We can remove it with:

```
chat_raw <- chat_raw[!is.na(time)]
time <- time[!is.na(time)]
```

To get this into a nice format, let's make a data.frame out of it:

```
tibble::tibble(
  time = time,
  text = chat_raw
)
#> # A tibble: 7 x 2
#>   time            text                                                     
#>   <chr>           <chr>                                                    
#> 1 12/07/2017, 22~ 12/07/2017, 22:35 - Messages to this group are now secur~
#> 2 12/07/2017, 22~ 12/07/2017, 22:35 - You created group 'Tes'              
#> 3 12/07/2017, 22~ 12/07/2017, 22:35 - Johannes Gruber: <Media omitted>     
#> 4 12/07/2017, 22~ 12/07/2017, 22:35 - Johannes Gruber: Fruit bread with ch~
#> 5 13/07/2017, 09~ 13/07/2017, 09:12 - Test: It's fun doing text analysis w~
#> 6 13/07/2017, 09~ 13/07/2017, 09:16 - Johannes Gruber: Haha it sure is <U+~
#> 7 28/09/2018, 13~ 28/09/2018, 13:27 - Johannes Gruber: Did you know there ~
```

Here you go, nice and clean output :)

If you want to do more with your whatsapp data, work through the [demo of my package](https://github.com/JBGruber/rwhatsapp#demo). I haven't posted it on CRAN since I think the contribution is a bit small so far but if you can think of cool functions, I can add them and maybe over time this becomes a legitimate package.